# Custom Layout on the WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I want to Set the Custom layout on the WebView.  ..
I have Done with the LinearLayout and the RelativeLayout but i cant seen the Layout on the WebView How it is Possible to do ? Please help me. . .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a parent layout(Say Relative Layout) and set your layout there and within it set a linear layout according to your need and add webview within it.
See the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_title_bg"
        ></ImageView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TitleText" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="About us" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        ></TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
    android:layout_below="@id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    >

<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

/>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this is what you want....

Comment: Thanks Budy but i have Set the Google Map Link in WebView. and While i am Viewing it, i cant seen the Layout and Default WebView is seen. . Can u help me out???

Comment: Sure, just replace the simple webview with Google MapView and customized the layout according to your requirement. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Ya Sure, but the Thing is that i am using WebView in My Application and parse the Ready made URl of the Source and Destination GeoPoint Address for getting  the Direction in Map. Now How to Get the Button or Layouy on that view ??? Any Idea ?

Comment: The Code u have Given is Not showing the Header part and The Button on the WebView. Please Check your code.

Comment: It will work , I have already used this code. Make sure tha you are using any image(drawable) named **main_title_bg** for ImageView and keep WebView in a separate layout as i did in the above code. and all other layout separately.Hope you got my point....?

Comment: Dear Friend I got your point and You are right in normal way. but listen i am Parse the URL that Contain the ReadyMade Geopoint for Getting Direction in Map. See My Code Below in Next Comment then u got My idea. .

Comment: StringBuffer mapUrl = new StringBuffer();
// OnCreate Method

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mapUrl.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?");
mapUrl.append("saddr="+21.22794190505816+","+72.8173828125);
mapUrl.append("&daddr="+23.039297747769726+","+72.59765);

Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(mapUrl.toString()));
startActivity(i);
// Hope Now yout got the Idea. . .

Comment: Have you any Answer for My Question ?

Comment: Ok , Now whats the problem. Do you want to show only the direction or want to go to the get direction page through the button on google Map View.....

Comment: I want to Set My Own Back button With own Title on the Google MapView. But Listen i have Use WebView to Load the URL and it will call in New Activity. Please Help me.. .

Comment: If you want to set the layout for direction page I think its not possible because in that we are using the default google URI for map.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But If it is Possible then let me know. . .